# Touch is working on <p> tag is for specific place

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

> Classification and Distance dropdown function is working for one specific (**Red Spot**)place click.When I click except that place of Classification and Distance dropdown it is not working .

[image]

> Here my code for that

```
 <div class="uct-grid viewtask-grid">
                  <ion-list>
                      <ion-item class="item-divider">
                          <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                              <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name='title' ng-model="jobsearch.jobTitle">
                          </label>                          
                      </ion-item>

                      <ion-item class="item-divider item-select viewtask-top">
                        <p>Classification:
                          <select ng-model="jobsearch.classification" ng-change="changeClassification(jobsearch.classification)"
                                  ng-options="classification as classification.name for classification in classifications track by classification.id">
                          </select>
                        </p>
                      </ion-item>

                      <ion-item class="item-divider item-select viewtask-top">
                        <p>Distance:
                          <select ng-model="jobsearch.distance" ng-change="changeDistance(jobsearch.distance)"
                                  ng-options="distance as distance.name for distance in distances track by distance.id">
                          </select>
                        </p>
                        <!--<button type="submit" ng-click="searchJobs()" class="button button-block button-positive">SEARCH</button>-->
                      </ion-item>

                  </ion-list>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you checking your application on web or on your mobile device ? If on browser, are there any console errors ?

Comment: I checked in both.Same result when I click middle of the Category and left side of Distance it will show dropdown.Otherwise not.

Comment: Only Red pot touch is working.

Comment: Please check for the width(for the select, paragraph tag and for the ion-item). Make it full-width(100%).

Comment: please try increasing width of `<select>` tag